# How to sort Vector of Points based on specific two segment line

Tags: sorting, c++11, vector

[schema of point  & segment line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AfqI.png)

```
Point2f s; /*if I try to sort by point 50,0 for ex & distance from it*/
s.x = 50;
s.y = 0;     

bool tryToSort (const Point2f& sr, const Point2f& sl){
/* my distance calculation */
}


std::sort(VectorCoord.begin(), VectorCoord.end(), [s] (const Point2f& sr, const Point2f& sl){return tryToSort(s, sr) < ryToSort(s, sl)});
```

in these way I sort vector point by distance from point "s" ... but I can sort first by X axis than by distance from vertical line in my draw ... Is possible to make these in only one std::sort call?

giorgio

Comment: I edited your **sorting** tag to **sort**

Answer (score 0):

I canceled my answer because it was a new question on the matter and the previous question is resolved

Comment: If you have another question, just **edit** your first one and add it to, **NOT** as an answer to yours

Comment: thanks k-five .... but if cancel my answer + new question I cancel your comment too ... I can make these?

Comment: Just delete your answer. That is it. You cannot delete mine, answer nor commant